# Remove the aspxerrorpath param with CustomErrors use ResponseRewrite

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, custom-error-pages

I'm using asp.net MVC4 + visual studio 2012. every thing all fine, But only the custom error always has the **aspxerrorpath** param on the URL.

I already config the custom error on **web.config**:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Error">
  <error redirect="~/Error/Error" statusCode="404" />
  <error redirect="~/Error/Error" statusCode="500" />
</customErrors>
```

I also changed my Error Action to :

```
public ActionResult Error()
{
    Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
    return View();
}
```

Will now when there is some 404 happening. I always got aspxerrorpath param on my URL.
**I tried add `redirectMode="ResponseRewrite"`** to the customError nodes but If add this , the error will display a run time exception.....

So Is there any best way to remove the aspxerrorpath param? Thanks.

Comment: @AmirHossein Mehrvarzi Looks like you're not see my question, I said I already tried solution: redirectMode="ResponseRewrite",  but It's not working.

Comment: @AmirHossein Mehrvarzi these problems already finish, but no any one can fixed my problem.

Comment: @AmirHosseinMehrvarzi, I fixed it use another way, you need to remove the ``Already answer`` link.

Answer (score 7):

Another simple solution is turning on `customErrors` in `web.config` file for 404 error:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/home/notfound" />
</customErrors>
```

and in home controller:

```
public ActionResult NotFound(string aspxerrorpath)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(aspxerrorpath))
        return RedirectToAction("NotFound");

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect" />
```

in `<system.web>...</system.web>`, than in my default action's (in the default controller), on the first line I wrote following:

```
if (Request["aspxerrorpath"] != null) return RedirectToAction(this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString());
```

It is dirty resolve, but effective.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I close the customErrors

```
<customErrors  mode="Off"></customErrors>
```

Then I use **httpErrors** to replace it.

```
<httpErrors  errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="400"/>
      <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/BadRequest"/>
      <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/AccessDenied" />
          <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFound" />
      <remove statusCode="500"/>
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Error" />
</httpErrors>
```

Now All fine.

**Update 1**

But it will display the **exception details** sometimes , So now I use :

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Main/Error" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
      <error redirect="~/Main/NotFound" statusCode="404" />
      <error redirect="~/Main/Error" statusCode="500" />
      <error redirect="~/Main/AccessDenied" statusCode="403" />
      <error redirect="~/Main/BadRequest" statusCode="400" />
    </customErrors> 


 <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="400" />
      <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Main/BadRequest" />
      <remove statusCode="403" />
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Main/AccessDenied" />
      <remove statusCode="404" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Main/NotFound" />
      <remove statusCode="500" />
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Main/Error" />
    </httpErrors>
```

I think still not find best solution for now. also don't understand why the Microsoft design like that. Maybe want every one know the website based on **.NET**

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue the aspx error path is set from my IIS server. so check your IIS settings:

```
your project > Authentication > Forms Authentic
```

**In form authentication right click Edit and check your URL.**

I have problem in that url path remove the extension `.aspx`  and it working fine.

Comment: Hi, I'm not use any Authentication in my project.  and I'm using IIS7.5 with it . I'm use MVC4. not use .aspx view page

Comment: @qakmak i am using MVC4  razor syntax with iis7. but it automatically add .aspx at the end of my default page.

Comment: Not mine, I'm alredy remove aspx view engine from Global.asax use :ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();. my error url like:http://127.0.0.1/Error/Error?aspxerrorpath=/

Answer (score 0):

Use Redirect inside your mvc action.

For example in config you can have "~/Error", in controller have Index action (default action) that redirects to Error action (I would call it PageNotFound) - querystring will be lost on redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/404.html"  redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error redirect="/403.html" statusCode="403"  />
    <error redirect="/404.html" statusCode="404" />
    <error redirect="/500.html" statusCode="500" />
  </customErrors>
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolute simplest solution is to use a blank querystring in the defaultRedirect in web.config to override (note the question mark):

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/error?" mode="On" />
</system.web>
```